# 500 internal server error elastic beanstalk flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my simple EB project with Python - Flask but I am getting the below error. It is running in local virtual environment without any issue.

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

My application.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

requirements.txt:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

My Zip file contains:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `application.py` is incorrect. Instead `app` it should be `application`:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

You still may have other errors which are not apparent yet though.

Comment: @Natarajanprakash Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: WHAT!!!
Surprised it worked out, but what is the difference between `app` and `application`? :D

Comment: @MahmoudReda From python perspective there is no difference. But EB expects your app to be called `application`, not `app`. Its EB default value.